# Angular2 changing date format in the ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, date, ag-grid

```
columnDefs:any[] = [
     {headerName: 'Incident Id', field: 'incidentId'},
        {headerName: 'Time', field: '{{incidentTime |  date: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'}}'}

    ];
```

where **incidentTime** is in timestamp format 1488225600000(which is 28/02/2017), but pipe doesn't work.

How can I convert this date into require format.

Answer (score 0):

Add celltemplate and type like this:

```
type: 'date',
cellTemplate: '{{incidentTime |  date: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'}}'
```

Comment: {headerName: 'Time', cellTemplate: '{{incidentTime | date: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'}}'}, returns empty

Comment: Its not working, I handled it in server side . Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you are handling it in server side? Does you incidentTime type is string?

Comment: @JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a")
 private Date incidentTime;

Comment: Ah ok, so you now have the desired result and no need to format it in ag-grid right?

Comment: Yes, Its difficult to achieve in client side

Comment: For my project the timestamp is being return as numeric in json, and I do manipulate the date formats in ag-grid just like my answer above. The only problem I saw in formatting it directly in the backend is that you cannot make use of the date column filter for ag-grid.

Comment: Tried this not working.   {headerName: 'incident Time', type: 'date',
cellTemplate: '{{1488225600000 |  date: \'dd/MM/yyyy\'}}'},